# Get ExternalInterface definitions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, externalinterface

Is there a way to get a list of the exposed functions from a Flash object? For example, you could get a list of all methods in an object by executing:

```
for (var i in object) {
  if (typeof object[i] == "function") {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

The only issue is that this won't expose any methods registered through the  ExternalInterfaces API. I can try and see if the function exists (`object['method']`) and it tells me it is a function, but I would have to guess every existing method in this manner.

NOTE: Obviously, I don't have access to the actionscript.

Answer (score 2):

Just hit this question, a tad to late it seems, but I'll post an answer anyways ;)
Using IE10 (windows 7) it worked perfectly fine for me to list all my methods like so:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('flashObj');
for(var prop in obj){
  var fx = obj[prop];
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && (typeof fx == 'function') && /eval\(instance/.test(fx)){
    console.log(prop)
  }
}
```

Note that this did not work in Chrome or Firefox and only with the exact regexp since IE10 does not report "native code" as the other browsers do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is even worse: the information is neither available in ActionScript. You register a new function as `ExternalInterface.addCallback('foo', foo)` and you can not list already registered callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but see if it works. All the ExternalInterface functions should be defined in the global namespace. Try embedding the SWF in an HTML page and get all the Javascript functions defined for the page after the page has loaded. [List of global user defined functions in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493833/list-of-global-user-defined-functions-in-javascript)

The list of functions should be those defined in the SWF file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way to go is to parse the SWF file bytecode and try to gather the calls to `ExternalInterface.addCallback` method.

http://www.google.com/search?q=parse+avm2

Answer (score -1):

My instinct is no, ExternalInterface is essentially a black box, or black letter box, you poke things through and sometimes things come back, but you can't open the door to see what's inside.

Without documentation as to what's been exposed in the SWF, the only other suggestion is decompiling the swf to have a look at the source.