# Enumeration javascript functions/objects defined in a js file

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of global user defined functions in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493833/list-of-global-user-defined-functions-in-javascript)

I have a java script file (.js) which contains some functions:

```
function func1(arg)
{
}

function func2(arg)
{
}

...
```

I want to enumerate all functions defined in js file.
Is there a root object in javascript to enum all sub objects by it? (by methods defined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object))

**Ugly solutions:**

One approach is to define an array like:
var functions = [func1, func2, ...];

Another approach is string processing (such as regular expressions):

/function.+(.+)/

I there better solution for it?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has a root object, just open a console and type `this`, or `window` for that matter. If you want to list all functions in the global object, just treat the global object as you would any object:

```
for (var property in this)
{
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(property) && typeof this[property] === 'function')
    {
        console.log(property + ' is a function');
    }
}
```

You *could* leave out the `.hasOwnProperty` check, but remember that all objects, including `window` can be traced back to the `Object.prototype`, so you might end up enumerating prototype-methods, too. What's more, the global object has its own prototype, too: `Window.prototype`. 
A word of warning: when it comes to X-browser issues, the global object is one of the worst objects to deal with. IE, Mozilla, Chrome, Opera *and* Safari all have differences between them, some more then others.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
var Stub = new Object();

Stub.func1 = function(args) {/*Your code*/};
Stub.func2 = function(args) {/*Your code*/};
Stub.func3 = function(args) {/*Your code*/};

// enumerate through functions

for(f in Stub)
{
   if (Stub.hasOwnProperty(f) && typeof Stub[f] === "function")
       console.log(f);
}
```

I am treating object '`Stub`' as a namespace/class here.

**EDIT:** In case you have no control over the JS file, third party perhaps, you can still use the above technique to figure out the list of functions in the file. I am assuming the js file is defining new functions on the global namespace (window). Here's what you do:

Step 1: Run the above script and store all the functions on window (replace Stub with window) in an array.

Step 2: Dynamically load the new JS file ([by adding a script tag linking to the external js file into the HEAD via JavaScript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)) and after the JS file is loaded (i.e. in ready state), run the above script again.

Step 3: Any function reported in step 2 that was not already visited in step 1 is the new subset introduced by the JS file.

- So there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate all global function using `window`. but it contains many other properties.

```
for(var fun in window){

   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty hacked up approach; it enumerates the `window` global object and filters out those that are listed as `[native code]`.

```
for (var i in window) {
    if (window.hasOwnProperty(i) &&
          'function' === typeof window[i] && 
          !Function.toString.call(window[i]).match('\[native code\]')) { 
        console.log(i) 
    } 
}
```

Probably not very cross-browser though, it worked on Chrome. It would be better if you could place all your functions inside a namespace.