# Capture functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any specific way for me to capture functions that have been defined in a Javascript file?
It is for testing purposes for me to choose functions I want to perform tests in the Javascript file.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Could you explain more what you want to achieve? Do you want to make a text file with all the names of the functions or what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of global user defined functions in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493833/list-of-global-user-defined-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: I want to build a web page where the user will be asked to upload a certain javascript file and then all functions found in that file would be captured where the user could select upon which functions tests will be performed. may be in a drop down list or something

Comment: feel free to steal my  getNatives() function from http://danml.com/packager/, i think ittl work for this...

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically get a list of all the user-defined global functions as follows:

```
var listOfFunctions = [];
for (var x in window) {
if (window.hasOwnProperty(x) && 
  typeof window[x] === 'function' &&
  window[x].toString().indexOf('[native code]') < 0)
    listOfFunctions.push(x);      
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/aDeBunej/1/edit?html,js,output)

The `listOfFunctions` array will contain the names of all the global functions which are not native.

The above won't work in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier for [global function declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression).

Comment: but that says what's in window, not a certain file, and it would hit already-loaded functions, not just the file's.

Comment: no but this is not what I am looking for.
I would like to have a list of all the functions in the file whether loaded or not. For selection in testing.